# Jquery methods won't add HTML to DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was trying to add data to my existing table using Jquery's append(), but for some reason it did not work. I found another way to solve this problem, but I was wondering why this solution did not work. Could anyone explain it to me?

JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var mapItems=new Map();
    mapItems.set("firstName", "First Name");
    mapItems.set("lastName", "Last Name");
    mapItems.set("dob", "Date of Birth");
    mapItems.set("gender", "Gender");
    mapItems.set("idnumber", "ID Number");
    mapItems.set("occupation", "Occupation");
    mapItems.set("ethnicity", "Ethinicity");

    function viewAllItems(data){
        var info="";
        for(var x=0; x<data.length;x++){
            info+="<th>";
            for(var key of mapItems.keys()){
                var added=data[x][key];
                added="<tr>"+added;
                added+="</tr>";
                info+=added;
            }
            info+="</th>";
        }
        return info;
    }

$("#viewAll").on('click', function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"A_URL_THAT_RETURNS_DATA",  
            type: "GET",
            success:function(data) { 
                $("#tableViewAll").children().remove();
                $("#tableViewAll").append(viewAllItems(data));
            }
    });
});
});
```

HTML

```
<button id="viewAll">View All</button><br>
        <table id=tableViewAll>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Date of Birth</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
                <th>ID number</th>
                <th>Occupation</th>
                <th>Ethnicity</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

After console.logging viewAllItems(data), I got a proper HTML string back as a result, here it is:

```
<th><tr>sdfsdf</tr><tr>asdfasd</tr><tr>2006-03-04</tr><tr>male</tr>    <tr>234234234</tr><tr>sadf</tr><tr>hispanic</tr></th><th><tr>John</tr><tr>Smith</tr><tr>1997-05-23</tr><tr>male</tr><tr>456456456</tr><tr>Garbageman</tr><tr>asian</tr></th><th><tr>aasd</tr><tr>asdfffe</tr><tr>2009-06-07</tr><tr>male</tr><tr>789789789</tr><tr>dfhdfbfdgb</tr><tr>hispanic</tr></th>
```

The information inside doesn't make any sense(on purpose) and is formatted poorly, but I just wanted to show that I get a proper HTML string back as a response. 
Thus, my append method should append this string into the table. However, it does not do so.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I just want to understand why it didn't work the way I thought it would.

P.S. I realize that I'm deleting my table headings, that's to be fixed. Also, I realized i'm using the th tag when I shouldn't be, but I'll also fix that later

Comment: Your generated HTML is invalid. You have the `<tr>` elements inside a `<th>`. Should be the other way around... `info+="<th>";` ... `added="<tr>"+added;`... etc.

Comment: ...other way around... `info+="<tr>";` ... `added="<th>"+added;`... etc.

Comment: *"...I realized i'm using the th tag when I shouldn't be, but I'll also fix that later..."* Why later? *That's* what is causing the issue. If you know something is wrong, and you get unexpected behavior, wouldn't the first step be to fix the wrong stuff?

Comment: And you can see it here: https://jsfiddle.net/ercb8wq0/

Comment: @squint Thanks for the help, I didn't realize that it was due to the wrong tags, but something else. It works now though! Thanks again

Comment: @YashSanghavi: You're welcome. HTML elements have semantic meaning, so in some cases when you use them in semantically incorrect ways, the browser does corrections when creating the DOM nodes. In your case, the browser was seeing `<tr>` elements in the `<th>` and was kicking them and their content out. So that's why nothing showed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generated table row is wrapped in a TH. Also there is no TD present inside TR. Please correct that and the code should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It worked after I made those changes. This was my first time using Stack Overflow and I was surprised by the quick responses from everyone. Thanks a ton!